# What is window.WebGLRenderingContext?

Tags: javascript, webgl

What is the difference between `window.WebGLRenderingContext` and `canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl')`?

I've searched a lot, but I can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It might help if you shared what you found in your search.

Comment: Nothing useful. This is a function, and if `!!window.WebGLRenderingContext` is false, then webgl is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas.getContext` will return a drawing context for that particular canvas (see [spec §2: *Context Creation*](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#2)). It will likely inherit from the global and static `window.WebGLRenderingContext` object, which exposes the [`WebGLRenderingContext` interface (spec §5.14)](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#5.14). A browser does not need to expose those native interfaces to the DOM scripting API, but they usually do.

Answer (score 3):

What they said :-)

One more thing, you can use it with `instanceof` as in

```
> c = document.createElement("canvas");
<canvas>​
> gl = c.getContext("experimental-webgl")
WebGLRenderingContext
> gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext
true
```

Comment: ps: I just typed those lines in the JavaScript console so `>` is the prompt in the console.

Answer (score 1):

WebGLRenderingContext is a native implementation (or is allowed to be), and isn't meant to be called by the end-user, directly, in order to do work.

At least, not as it currently-exists.

Really, you can use it to see if WebGL is supported:

```
if (!!window.WebGLRenderingContext) { 
    /* webGL is 100% guaranteed to be supported in this browser,
       if browser follows standards */
}
```

or

```
if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext) { /* software fallback */ }
```

But it can not be used directly.

Comment: Checking for the presence of `window.WebGLRenderingContext` does NOT guarantee that WebGL is supported in the browser. For example, `window.WebGLRenderingContext` exists in Chrome for Android, but it's simply not usable.

Comment: @MichaelMcTiernan I'm sorry, and you're right. Technically, there are some browsers which support the context which do not actually enable it...   ...but http://www.engadget.com/2013/01/25/chrome-beta-for-android-makes-webgl-easy-to-toggle/