# How to know if a canvas is a normal canvas or a webgl canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

How to know if a canvas is running a "WebGL" or just normal canvas?

from inspecting the source, I find it a canvas in either case.

Comment: Look for window.WebGLRenderingContext. 
More [info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938600/what-is-window-webglrenderingcontext)

Answer (score 8):

That really depends and how you want to go about finding out.

For example you could call `getContext' like this

```
if (someCanvas.getContext("2d")) {
  // It's a 2D canvas
} else if (someCanvas.getContext("experimental-webgl") || 
           someCanvas.getContext("webgl")) {
  // It's a WebGL canvas
}
```

Unfortunately that will also make the canvas a 2D canvas if no one has previously called `getContext`.

Another option is you could wrap getContext something like this

```
(function() {

  var originalGetContextFunction = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;

  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function() {
    var type = arguments[0];
    var ctx = originalGetContextFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    if (ctx && !this.canvasType) {
      this.canvasType = type;
    }
    return ctx;
  };

}());
```

Now for any canvas you can check `someCanvas.canvasType` to find out what string was passed into `getContext`. Example:

```
var c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
var c2 = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");
var gl = c2.getContext("experimental-webgl");
alert("c1 is " + c1.canvasType + ", c2 is " + c2.canvasType);
```

Just make sure the wrapper is included before any code that creates canvases.

Comment: where we should run that IIFE function? can we know it from a console devtools?

Answer (score 3):

Canvas doesn't run anything - it is just an element with a modifiable bitmap in both cases. It cannot, by itself, tell what it is being used for.

Canvas can supply you with ***contexts*** though which can be either. If you for some reason is not able to see in the source code what context is being requested you can always test the *context* (a bit backward but here goes):

```
if (ctx === null) {
    return 'unsupported';
}
else if (typeof ctx.viewport === 'undefined' && // test some existing non-shared
         typeof ctx.arc !== 'undefined') {      // method names
    return '2d';
}
else if (typeof ctx.viewport !== 'undefined' &&
         typeof ctx.arc === 'undefined') {
    return 'webgl';
}
else {
    return 'unknown';
}
```

Testing for `WebGLRenderingContext` will not help as this test support in the *browser*. It is not given that you will get a WebGL context even if the browser supports WebGL as this is dependent on the computer and its hardware-capability as well.

Comment: so that means I cannot know if the currently running canvas in my browser is using webgl or not, just by inspecting elements? without getting my hand dirty with javascript?

Comment: @MahmoudBadri the code used should reveal what is being used :) You can search for 2d or webgl (or experimental-webgl) to find it in the source code (hit ctrl+ u to get the source of the page).

Comment: yeah I know, but it is a js library called pixijs, it uses webgl by default and falls back to canvas. I just wanted to know if it is currently using webgl or canvas in my browser :)

Comment: How do I get the currently used context of a `<canvas>` on the page?

Answer (score 2):

if you do `canvas.getContext('2d')` and it return `null` its not a 2d context, same for the other context types.  If on the other hand the context is not yet created, it will create the context.

Comment: This actually works! In Chrome, after inspecting the element, you can do $0.getContext('2d'). And if it returns null it is not a 2d context.